# What is the use of 'n_splits' in StratifiedShuffleSplit from scikit learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have been reading the book Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow and I found this code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

I would like to know what the argument 'n_splits' does. I searched everywhere but couldn't find a satisfactory response.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, the n_splits parameter is used to specify how many times (basically how many separate splits) you want the splits to happen.

For example, setting n_splits = 3 would make the loop generate 3 different splits (one for each iteration) so you can perform validation more effectively.

Setting n_splits = 1 would mimic what sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split would do (along with the stratify parameter mentioned). The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) has detailed explanations of each parameter for this function.

Comment: So n_splits = 3 would create 3 sets of training and testing splits? How does that help to train the model? Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Yes, 3 sets. Creating multiple splits would allow you to train a new model on each split allows the validation to be more accurate and averaging the output of all these models would lead to a more robust model overall. This concept is more well known as Repeated K-Fold Cross Validation.